# How to loop through an n-dimensional list and find all combinations

Tags: python, arrays, list, dice

I wrote a program to roll some dice together. The way it works is I pass in the dice I want to roll to the main function, `[4, 6]` aka 4 sided dice and 6 sided dice.
The program then generates 2 lists that contain all the possible outcomes for the dice individually

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Then, I make a list of all possible outcomes and just add every combination of data between the two lists. Here's my code

```
#list of outcomes from current dice rolling - to contain sublists within it for each dice
rawDiceOutcomes = []

#list of total outcomes to find probabilities in
finalOutcomes = []

#generate n lists of outcomes 
for i in range(len(dice)):
    rawDiceOutcomes.append([i for i in range(1, dice[i]+1)])    #[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] etc


#TODO : Figure out some way to do this for an n-dimensional list
for x in rawDiceOutcomes[0]:   
    for y in rawDiceOutcomes[1]:
        tempOutcome = x + y
        finalOutcomes.append(tempOutcome)
```

As the commentary shows, I know how to do this if only rolling 2 dice, but eventually, I want to be able to pass in 3, 4, 100 dice etc. How would I go about looping through all the lists so that I can pass in any number of dice and it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a general approach with any dice:

```
from itertools import product

dice = [4, 6]

individual_outcomes = [range(1, d+1) for d in dice]

combined_outcomes = [*map(sum, product(*individual_outcomes))]
```

Comment: Any advantages of your approach over `list(map(sum, product(*individual_outcomes)))`?

Comment: 3 bytes of code :D

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate any combinations for any number of list:

```
import itertools

rawDiceOutcomes = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
res = [sum(comb) for comb in itertools.product(*rawDiceOutcomes)]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

The above code remains unchange for any length of `rawDiceOutcomes`.